# URL redirect not recognized

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests, http-redirect

I'm trying to download a video from TikTok using its video ID [link](https://api2.musical.ly/aweme/v1/play/?video_id=v09044a20000beeff4c108gs7sflfdug).

In the browser, the above link redirects me to the full video [URL](http://v16.muscdn.com/e8cee4f83f4c598a9d13ba6e4f7cead2/5d058940/video/tos/maliva/tos-maliva-v-0068/e5a1ab74d0b54f97b3578924a428e58d/?rc=amdvdnY7NDdpaDMzNTczM0ApQHRAbzg5ODozOjM0NDY0Ozg5PDNAKXUpQGczdSlAZjN2KUBmaGhkbGRlemhoZGY2NUByY2M0ZC1gY2JfLS1eMTZzczVvI28jQjItLzEuLi0tLS4uLi0uL2k6YjBwIzphLXEjOmAtbyNqdFxtK2IranQ6IzAuXg%3D%3D.).

When I try using `requests.get`, I get no `response.history`, meaning that `requests` thinks that there was no redirect.

```py
import urllib.request
import requests

post_url = "https://api2.musical.ly/aweme/v1/play/?video_id=v09044a20000beeff4c108gs7sflfdug"
vid_url = "http://v16.muscdn.com/e8cee4f83f4c598a9d13ba6e4f7cead2/5d058940/video/tos/maliva/tos-maliva-v-0068/e5a1ab74d0b54f97b3578924a428e58d/?rc=amdvdnY7NDdpaDMzNTczM0ApQHRAbzg5ODozOjM0NDY0Ozg5PDNAKXUpQGczdSlAZjN2KUBmaGhkbGRlemhoZGY2NUByY2M0ZC1gY2JfLS1eMTZzczVvI28jQjItLzEuLi0tLS4uLi0uL2k6YjBwIzphLXEjOmAtbyNqdFxtK2IranQ6IzAuXg%3D%3D"

response = requests.get(post_url)
if response.history:
    print("Request was redirected")
    for resp in response.history:
        print(resp.status_code, resp.url)
    print("Final destination:")
    print(response.status_code, response.url)
else:
    print("Request was not redirected")
```

This results in `Request was not redirected`.

How can I get the redirect URL from the `response`?

Comment: Chances are you're getting an error because the server understands that the request is made from a script, not from a real browser. Try inspecting the status and body of the response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a header, try replacing this:

```
response = requests.get(post_url)
```

with this:

```
response = requests.get(post_url, headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0", "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"})
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to download the video all you have to do is to request for the vid_url and then write the video as a file.

```
import urllib.request
import requests

post_url = "https://api2.musical.ly/aweme/v1/play/?video_id=v09044a20000beeff4c108gs7sflfdug"
vid_url = "http://v16.muscdn.com/e8cee4f83f4c598a9d13ba6e4f7cead2/5d058940/video/tos/maliva/tos-maliva-v-0068/e5a1ab74d0b54f97b3578924a428e58d/?rc=amdvdnY7NDdpaDMzNTczM0ApQHRAbzg5ODozOjM0NDY0Ozg5PDNAKXUpQGczdSlAZjN2KUBmaGhkbGRlemhoZGY2NUByY2M0ZC1gY2JfLS1eMTZzczVvI28jQjItLzEuLi0tLS4uLi0uL2k6YjBwIzphLXEjOmAtbyNqdFxtK2IranQ6IzAuXg%3D%3D"

response = requests.get(vid_url)

with open("python_logo.mp4",'wb') as f:

    # Saving received content as a mp4 file in
    # binary format

    # write the contents of the response
    # to a new file in binary mode.
    f.write(response.content)
```

It's working i have checked. Hope you got what you were looking for

Comment: This does not answer the question. Maybe it was a bit misleading that `vid_url` was included in the original code, but the question was how to get this URL (i.e. the target of the HTTP redirect), not how to download a file from that URL.